# Adding new element into 3 dimensional array NUMPY

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array, which shape's is equal to (1,59,1)
It looks in the following way:

```
[[[0.93169003]
  [0.96923472]
  [0.97881434]
  [0.99266784]
  [0.97358235]
  ............
  [0.83777312]
  [0.82086134]]]
```

I wish I could add new element to the end, which is equal to [[0.86442673]], so that the shape of my array would be equal to (1,60,1) and would look in the following way:

```
[[[0.93169003]
  [0.96923472]
  [0.97881434]
  [0.99266784]
  [0.97358235]
  ............
  [0.83777312]
  [0.82086134]
  [0.86442673]]]
```

I tried with np.append but it doesn't work for me. Please, help me

Comment: What was the error?  "Doesn't work for me" is not a polite of describing the problem.  Also show exactly how you use `np.append`.

Comment: I mean there is no error, but the array doesn't change. Its shape is still (1,59,1) and there is no new value

Comment: I used it as np.append(X_test ,pred_price)

Comment: X_test - my table, pred_price - the value I want to add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
arr=np.append(arr,[[[0.86442673]]], axis=1)
```

Where `arr` is your input array

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation :  "Note that append does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and filled". You have to assign the result to a variable to get the result.

```
X_test = np.append(X_test ,pred_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use numpy.insert

```
import numpy as np
d=np.random.randint(1,3,(2,5,3))
print(type(d),'\n',d.shape,'\n',d)
```

gives

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 
 (2, 5, 3) 
 [[[1 1 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [1 1 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [2 1 1]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [2 1 2]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 2 2]]]
```

then

```
#numpy.insert(arr, obj, values, axis=None)[source]   obj is the index, axis is the dimension number
e=np.insert(d,1,5,0)
print(f'e\n{e}')
f=np.insert(d,1,5,1)
print(f'f\n{f}')
g=np.insert(d,1,5,2)
print(f'g\n{g}')
```

gives

```
e
[[[1 1 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [1 1 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [2 1 1]]

 [[5 5 5]
  [5 5 5]
  [5 5 5]
  [5 5 5]
  [5 5 5]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [2 1 2]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 2 2]]]
f
[[[1 1 2]
  [5 5 5]
  [2 2 2]
  [1 1 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [2 1 1]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [5 5 5]
  [2 2 2]
  [2 1 2]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 2 2]]]
g
[[[1 5 1 2]
  [2 5 2 2]
  [1 5 1 2]
  [2 5 2 2]
  [2 5 1 1]]

 [[2 5 2 2]
  [2 5 2 2]
  [2 5 1 2]
  [1 5 1 1]
  [1 5 2 2]]]
```